# colorizing golang test run output

Tags: testing, go

I like it when terminal/console test runs actually show their output in either red or green text.  It seems like a lot of the testing libraries available for Go have this.  However, I'd like to just use the default testing package that comes with Go.  Is there a way to colorize it's output with red and green?

Comment: https://github.com/gotestyourself/gotestsum is another tool that does this (with watch feature...)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can create a wrapper shell script for this and color it using color escape sequence. Here's a simple example on Linux (I'm not sure how this would look on windows, but I guess there is a way.. :) )

```
go test -v . | sed ''/PASS/s//$(printf "\033[32mPASS\033[0m")/'' | sed ''/FAIL/s//$(printf "\033[31mFAIL\033[0m")/''
```

Comment: That's a good light weight solution.  I didn't think of just piping the output to sed.  It works.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I added -cover parameters and added it as alias. So everytime i want to run all tests i just run `got`

Comment: Beware that this solution loses exit code for `go test` which in turn means that if that command is used in some CI environment then build will not fail even if there are failing tests! One solution when using bash would be to use `pipefail`.

Comment: If anyone's using this command in their Makefile,  please replace $ with $$ for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 102):

**You can use [grc](https://github.com/garabik/grc/blob/master/grc), a generic colourizer, to colourize anything**.

On Debian/Ubuntu, install with `apt-get install grc`. On a Mac with , `brew install grc`.

Create a config directory in your home directory:

```
mkdir ~/.grc
```

Then create your personal grc config in `~/.grc/grc.conf`:

```
# Go
^([/\w\.]+\/)?go test\b
conf.gotest
```

Then create a Go test colourization config in `~/.grc/conf.gotest`, such as:

```
# go-test grc colorizer configuration
regexp==== RUN .*
colour=bright_blue
-
regexp=--- PASS: .* (\(\d+\.\d+s\))
colour=green, yellow
-
regexp=^PASS$
colour=bold white on_green
-
regexp=^(ok|FAIL)\s+.*
colour=default, magenta
-
regexp=--- FAIL: .* (\(\d+\.\d+s\))
colour=red, yellow
-
regexp=^FAIL$
colour=bold white on_red
-
regexp=[^\s]+\.go(:\d+)?
colour=cyan
```

Now you can run Go tests with:

```
grc go test -v ./..
```

Sample output:

[image: screenshot]

To avoid typing `grc` all the time, add an alias to your shell (if using Bash, either `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or both, depending on your OS):

```
alias go=grc go
```

Now you get colourization simply by running:

```
go test -v ./..
```

Comment: Great answer. Works like a charm.

Comment: The above colour specifier in the configuration causes `grcat` to throw `ValueError: Invalid keyword`. `grcat` expects the key `colours` instead (see [here](https://github.com/pengwynn/grc/blob/master/grcat#L101))

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a regression. `colour` works fine with grc 1.11.1.

Comment: an empty line is needed in the end of `~/.grc/conf.gotest` on mac os, with zsh and grc 1.11.1, otherwise it is trimming the last character of "cyan" and is looking for color "cya"

Comment: on mac os, with zsh and grc 1.11.1, I had to move grc.conf to  /usr/local/etc/grc.conf (conf.gotest stays as is) and add this in .zshrc `[[ -s "/usr/local/etc/grc.zsh" ]] && source /usr/local/etc/grc.zsh`

Answer (score 25):

There's also a tool called [richgo](https://github.com/kyoh86/richgo) that does exactly this, in a user-friendly way.

[image]

Comment: Now the owner of the repo is suggesting not to use this package

Answer (score 5):

[rakyll/gotest](https://github.com/rakyll/gotest) ([screenshot](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/2c01f8f54692b861595ca8c6207c1cefcef03a34/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f75646a57755a782e676966)) is a binary that does this.

Example:

```
$ gotest -v github.com/rakyll/hey
```

Answer (score 4):

You would still need a library to add color escape code like:

- for Windows: [`mattn/go-colorable`](https://github.com/mattn/go-colorable) or [`shiena/ansicolor`](https://github.com/shiena/ansicolor)
- for Unix or Windows: [`fatih/color`](https://github.com/fatih/color) or [`kortschak/ct`](https://github.com/kortschak/ct)
- for Unix or Windows: [`logrusorgru/aurora`](https://github.com/logrusorgru/aurora) (mentioned by [Ivan Black](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816872/ivan-black) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242652/colorizing-golang-test-run-output/27243620#comment68157915_27243620))

From there, you specify what you want to color (StdOut or StdErr, like [in this example](https://github.com/fatih/color/blob/35868b33b692dfbdba0e08abbca78e6114e2423d/color_test.go#L48))

Comment: Currently, `kortschak/ct` doesn't support Windows.

Comment: There is also [github.com/logrusorgru/aurora](https://github.com/logrusorgru/aurora) for Unix and Win10+, that supports Printf/Sprintf formatting. For example `fmt.Printf("value %d", Red(3))`

Comment: @IvanBlack Thank yo. I have added your link to the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

BoltDB has some test methods that look like this:

```
func assert(tb testing.TB, condition bool, msg string, v ...interface{}) {
    if !condition {
        _, file, line, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
        fmt.Printf("\033[31m%s:%d: "+msg+"\033[39m\n\n", append([]interface{}{filepath.Base(file), line}, v...)...)
        tb.FailNow()
    }
}
```

[Here are the rest](https://github.com/boltdb/bolt/blob/51f99c862475898df9773747d3accd05a7ca33c1/bolt_test.go).  I added the green dots [here](https://github.com/bentrevor/go-checkers/blob/master/src/bolt_test.go).

Answer (score 3):

## Emoji

You can use colors for text as others mentioned in their answers to have colorful text with a color code or using a third-party library.

But you can use **emojis** instead! for example, you can use`⚠️` for warning messages and  for error messages.

Or simply use these notebooks as a color:

```
: error message
: warning message
: ok status message
: action message
: canceled status message
: Or anything you like and want to recognize immediately by color
```

#### Bonus:

This method also helps you to quickly scan and find logs **directly in the source code**.

<sub>But some distributions of Linux default emoji font are not colorful by default and you may want to make them colorful, first.</sub>

Comment: How do I apply emojis? I'm guessing direct input as emojis via the configuration files

Comment: @BruceBigirwenkya they can be applied nicely to @Makpoc solution. Eg `sed ''/PASS/s//$(printf "\033[32m-PASS\033[0m")/'' | sed ''/FAIL/s//$(printf "\033[31m-FAIL\033[0m")/''`

Answer (score 1):

I like piping to a simple awk script for this. That way, you can customize with whatever colors/patterns suit you. You want to colorize an output unique to your project? Go for it.

Simply save this awk script to `./bin/colorize` in your project, `chmod 755 ./bin/colorize`, and customize to your needs:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# colorize - add color to go test output
# usage:
#   go test ./... | ./bin/colorize
#

BEGIN {
    RED="\033[31m"
    GREEN="\033[32m"
    CYAN="\033[36m"
    BRRED="\033[91m"
    BRGREEN="\033[92m"
    BRCYAN="\033[96m"
    NORMAL="\033[0m"
}
         { color=NORMAL }
/^ok /   { color=BRGREEN }
/^FAIL/  { color=BRRED }
/^SKIP/  { color=BRCYAN }
/PASS:/  { color=GREEN }
/FAIL:/  { color=RED }
/SKIP:/  { color=CYAN }
         { print color $0 NORMAL }

# vi: ft=awk
```

And then call your tests and pipe to `colorize` with:

`go test ./... | ./bin/colorize`

I find this method much easier to read and customize than the `sed` answers, and much more lightweight and simple than some external tool like `grc`.

Note: For the list of color codes, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#3-bit_and_4-bit).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested from Alexander Staubo's answer, one can use grc for getting colorized output.

On linux the config file is stored in **/etc/grc.conf**
Instead we can use the flag -c: **grc -c .grc/conf.gotest go test ….**
So we only need the **conf.gotest** file.