# Add something to bash to make keyword strings render a certain way?

Tags: bash

Is it possible to configure bash so that when certain keywords / strings are printed by a program or script they are highlighted by being rendered in a special way, different from the global configuration in one's profile?

I just clicked that this might be a very stupid question, because I'm talking about something that displays what's sent to `stdout` one char / one byte at a time...

**EDIT: The answer is to pipe the output through something like `sed`**

Context: I'm writing a bunch of unit tests using the builtin `testing` package for `Go` – and each time you run a test set with `go test` it prints the string `PASS` or `FAIL` depending on the result. It would be useful to colourise them in green and red, respectively. I think it *might* be overkill to create a fork of `golang/go` and modify the behaviour of the testing package to print in colours...

Example:

```
brAir:calc br$ go test
PASS
ok      github.com/benjamin-rood/abm-colour-polymorphism/calc   0.008s
brAir:calc br$
```

Comment: Can you provide a script example?

Comment: @moonbutt74 Well, it's not about the script, but about programming bash itself with specific handling when printing a string. I've given an example which will help to clarify, sorry, should have done that from the start.

Comment: There are a lot of suggestions here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267400/colour-highlighting-output-based-on-regex-in-shell . It's not a bash issue: bash starts the program running, and does not interfere in its output. So the program (`go test`) talks directly to the terminal window.

Comment: You seem to have somewhat answered your question in your question. While you can control what bash displays, unless you are piping all your output to a script or application that will check what is going to stdout before it is displayed, and then add the ANSI (or tput) color sequences -- what you `"clicked"` may be true...

Comment: More suggestions from a sister site: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/how-to-have-tail-f-show-colored-output

Comment: @rici that last link is particularly useful, thank you

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes it does seem like I've stubbed my toe on the answer while having my eyes half-closed as I typed, doesn't it? *`sigh`*

Comment: Ben, see [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242652/colorizing-golang-test-run-output) Specifically Makpoc 's answer. It might work?

Comment: @moonbutt74 – that's the answer indeed, I was searching in the wrong place, this is therefore effectively a duplicate of that question, and I will mark it myself as such.

Comment: Ben , do you do anything with C and ncurses? If so can you take a look at my question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553277/ncurses-printw-getting-correct-output-of-keycodes-for-return-and-space)

Comment: @moonbutt74 I'm sorry, I'm no help as I have only played with ncurses once ever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this in my shell test script:

```
... 
OK="\e[0;32mOK\e[00m"        # OK in green
FAIL="\e[0;31mFAIL\e[00m"  # this is red
SKIP="\e[0;33mSKIP\e[00m" # and this yellow
...
# then, for example:
test $res -eq 0 && { printf $OK ; ln -f ${TEST}.out ${TEST}_OK.out ; } || { printf $FAIL ; ln -f ${TEST}.out ${TEST}_FAILED.out ; }
....
```